# What are the benefits of serving semi-transparent images?

Tags: css, image, image-processing, png, transparency

For queries that Google interprets as pertaining to shopping, it populates a horizontal banner w/ (5 or so) sponsored product images @ the top of the search results page (before listing any actual hits).

I use [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) a lot & try to contribute by fixing any especially ugly automated inversions (as the creator merges user modifications daily) as I notice them.

Yesterday, I noticed that some of the aforementioned images were barely visible, I figured that they were mistakenly inverted so I inverted them once more to discover that I was wrong. After disabling Dark Reader, & following a few of the image links, I found that they were purposely made transparent (as in the actual pictures, NOT just the backgrounds). I saved & added a layer behind [1 of them](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuNrku27EvWtIn5xcC0_P-iGuKMdnX-YV2_6rtiLl34o2V0dR5T8B5KyBqSuCRcYtPtPX1J3kS_K0&usqp=CAc), to illustrate my point...

[image: 1st sponsored shopping result wrt "jackets" query]

If they only cut out the backgrounds & left the rest of the images alone, wouldn't the file sizes (& therefore the storage costs) be minimized?

Do they save money in some other way? Or are there any other reasons for why Google would serve images this way?

Comment: @MrLister Search "Jackets", hit F12, Ctrl+Shift+C, select an image, right click its src field, select "Copy link address", then you can right click & save the image.

Comment: The shorter/easier way is to just right click & "save image as" lol

Comment: I'll + the link to the image I used for illustration.